# Implicational logic confusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I am having trouble understanding how implicational statements are evaluated to be true or false. Take the statement

- if the 13 axioms of real numbers and $1=0$ are all true, then $1+1 \ne 1$ is true,

  i.e., "the 13 axioms of real numbers and $1=0$" implies "$1+1 \ne 1$".

1. Now, if "the 13 axioms of real numbers and $1=0$" is true, then $1+1 = 1+0 = 1,$ so $1+1 = 1,$ so "$1+1 \ne 1$" is false.

   That is, if "the 13 axioms of real numbers and $1=0$" is true, then "$1+1 \ne 1$" is false.

   This means that the given statement is **false**.
2. On the other hand, since "the 13 axioms and $1=0$" is false, the given statement, being "*false* implies "$1+1 \ne 1$", evaluates as **true**, according to the truth table.

Therefore, the given statement is both true and false. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - "the 13 axioms of real numbers and $1=0$" implies "$1+1 \ne 1$".
>
> 1. Now, if "the 13 axioms of real numbers and $1=0$" is true, then $1+1 = 1+0 = 1,$ so $1+1 = 1,$ so "$1+1 \ne 1$" is false.
>
>    That is, if "the 13 axioms of real numbers and $1=0$" is true, then "$1+1 \ne 1$" is false.
>
>    $\color\red{\text{This means that the given statement is }\textbf{false}.}$

The last line is implicitly assuming that whatever $P$ and $Q$ stand for, $$P\to \lnot Q\tag1$$ and $$P\to Q\tag2$$ have opposite truth values, that is, that they contradict each other. This assumption unfortunately does not hold: as a matter of fact, your otherwise-flawless argument gives a very example of these two sentences being **simultaneously true**.

Of course, statements $(1)$ and $(2)$ *sometimes* do have opposite truth values, for example, when $P$ stands for $\text“1=1\text{ or }1\ne1\text”.$ This does not automatically mean that they generally have opposite truth values.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to accept this one because it most explicitly states what the mistake in my thinking was.

Answer (score 1):

You've shown that a certain thing** --- let's call it $q$ --- implies both $p$ and $!p$. What that tells you is that $q$ is false. There's no mistake in this conclusion, nor any contradiction.

**The "thing" here is "The 13 axioms are true and 1 = 0".

Comment: But then wouldn't that mean that the implication statement (q implies p) evaluates soley to true, in which case (q implies p) cannot be false, yet I showed that (if q is true then p is false) which doesn't that show that (q implies p) is also false? I'm sorry I'm having a hard time with this.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is: if I show that (if p is true then q is false), then (even if p is always false) does this show that (p implies q) is true or not?

Comment: Taking your comment one phrase at a time: (1) yes, it means $q \implies p$ is true. (2) it also means that $q \implies p$ is not false. (3) You did show $q \implies !p$ as well. (4) You *want* to conclude, from $q \implies p$, that $q \implies !p$ is false, and *that* is the gap in your argument. It's quite possible for something to imply both $A$ and $!A$...and the only conclusion you can draw from that is that the "something" is false.

Comment: Okay, I understand now, thanks! I think you meant to say "You want to conclude, from q implies !p that, that q implies p is false"

Comment: You're probably right...I wasn't really thinking about the meanings of q and p as I wrote that, and getting a "sign" wrong would not surprise me. Glad it was of some help.

Answer (score 0):

The truth table for implication is given like this:

| $P$ | $Q$ | $P \to Q$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | True |
| **True** | **False** | **False** |
| False | True | True |
| False | False | True |

As you can see the full implication is only false when the first part is true and second part is false.

Your first part of the implication "the $13$ axioms of real numbers and $0 = 1$" is false. And as such the whole statement is always true, no matter if the second part is true or false.

How this can be interpreted is that whenever you start with a false claim, any implication from that claim is meaningless.
If I say that $0 = 1$, I can easily prove that $1 + 1 = 0$ and that $1 + 1 = 2$. But only one of those is actually true given normal rules of mathematics.